# HDD not found in CrystalDiskInfo

Tags: hard-drive, hitachi

I'm running Windows 7 Pro with a Hitachi HDS721010CLA332 HDD as my single (only) drive. This drive appears in the Device Manager (which is how I obtained the model number) and wmic (SMART) utility says it is "OK".

However, I suspect there are issues with this drive and so I downloaded CrystalDiskInfo7_7_0. My problem is that CrystalDiskInfo does not find my disk. I've tried running both DiskInfo32.exe and DiskInfo64.exe, but upon opening, both just show "Disk Not Found".

Is there a way in CrystalDiskInfo to force it to "discover" my disk?

Or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Does the drive show up at least in Disk Management? If the drive isn't correctly recognized at BIOS/UEFI or the OS then no software will be able to access it, not just the one you mentioned.

Comment: There is one possibility: if the motherboard contains an additional SATA controller and the disk is plugged into that instead of the "default" AHCI SATA controller included in the system chipset, you might have accidentally disabled the controller in BIOS or be missing a driver for it. But if that is not the problem, that kind of "total dying" is apparently a known failure mode for those disks. [Looks like it might be fixable by HDD circuit board swap.](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Hitachi+GST+Deskstar+HDS721010CLA332+Hard+Drive++Controller+Replacement/67695)

Comment: I have edited my original question to give more clarity, and it should answer Gabriela's question. TelcoM: If you think the controller or driver might be an issue, can you tell me how to check?

Comment: Is this post still on hold? I'm hoping someone can help.